# KafkaUtils.createDirectStream returns a "error: type arguments" in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I'm trying to consume a Kafka topic from Spark with KafkaUtils.createDirectStream. I don't know if it is a Scala or KafkaUtils/Spark issue.

Here is my call to createDirectStream:

```
val messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, KafkaAvroDecoder, KafkaAvroDecoder, EvtAct](
  ssc,
  kafkaParams,
  fromOffsets,
  messageHandler
)
```

When I compile the code (from maven), I have this error:

```
 [ERROR] C:\...\reader\Main.scala:60: error: type arguments [String,String,io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDecoder,io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDecoder,fr.sihm.reader.EvtAct] conform to the bounds of none of the overloaded alternatives of
[INFO]  value createDirectStream: [K, V, KD <: kafka.serializer.Decoder[K], VD <: kafka.serializer.Decoder[V], R](jssc: org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext, keyClass: Class[K], valueClass: Class[V], keyDecoderClass: Class[KD], valueDecoderClass: Class[VD], recordClass: Class[R], kafkaParams: java.util.Map[String,String], fromOffsets: java.util.Map[kafka.common.TopicAndPartition,Long], messageHandler: org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function[kafka.message.MessageAndMetadata[K,V],R])org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaInputDStream[R] <and> [K, V, KD <: kafka.serializer.Decoder[K], VD <: kafka.serializer.Decoder[V], R](ssc: org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext, kafkaParams: Map[String,String], fromOffsets: Map[kafka.common.TopicAndPartition,Long], messageHandler: kafka.message.MessageAndMetadata[K,V] => R)(implicit evidence$14: scala.reflect.ClassTag[K], implicit evidence$15: scala.reflect.ClassTag[V], implicit evidence$16: scala.reflect.ClassTag[KD], implicit evidence$17: scala.reflect.ClassTag[VD], implicit evidence$18: scala.reflect.ClassTag[R])org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.InputDStream[R]
[INFO]     val messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, KafkaAvroDecoder, KafkaAvroDecoder, EvtAct](
[INFO]                               ^
[ERROR] one error found
```

createDirectStream has 4 declarations:

```
  def createDirectStream[
    K: ClassTag,
    V: ClassTag,
    KD <: Decoder[K]: ClassTag,
    VD <: Decoder[V]: ClassTag,
    R: ClassTag] (
      ssc: StreamingContext,
      kafkaParams: Map[String, String],
      fromOffsets: Map[TopicAndPartition, Long],
      messageHandler: MessageAndMetadata[K, V] => R
  ): InputDStream[R] = {
    val cleanedHandler = ssc.sc.clean(messageHandler)
    new DirectKafkaInputDStream[K, V, KD, VD, R](
      ssc, kafkaParams, fromOffsets, cleanedHandler)
  }

  def createDirectStream[
    K: ClassTag,
    V: ClassTag,
    KD <: Decoder[K]: ClassTag,
    VD <: Decoder[V]: ClassTag] (
      ssc: StreamingContext,
      kafkaParams: Map[String, String],
      topics: Set[String]
  ): InputDStream[(K, V)] = {
    val messageHandler = (mmd: MessageAndMetadata[K, V]) => (mmd.key, mmd.message)
    val kc = new KafkaCluster(kafkaParams)
    val fromOffsets = getFromOffsets(kc, kafkaParams, topics)
    new DirectKafkaInputDStream[K, V, KD, VD, (K, V)](
      ssc, kafkaParams, fromOffsets, messageHandler)
  }

  def createDirectStream[K, V, KD <: Decoder[K], VD <: Decoder[V], R](
      jssc: JavaStreamingContext,
      keyClass: Class[K],
      valueClass: Class[V],
      keyDecoderClass: Class[KD],
      valueDecoderClass: Class[VD],
      recordClass: Class[R],
      kafkaParams: JMap[String, String],
      fromOffsets: JMap[TopicAndPartition, JLong],
      messageHandler: JFunction[MessageAndMetadata[K, V], R]
    ): JavaInputDStream[R] = {
    implicit val keyCmt: ClassTag[K] = ClassTag(keyClass)
    implicit val valueCmt: ClassTag[V] = ClassTag(valueClass)
    implicit val keyDecoderCmt: ClassTag[KD] = ClassTag(keyDecoderClass)
    implicit val valueDecoderCmt: ClassTag[VD] = ClassTag(valueDecoderClass)
    implicit val recordCmt: ClassTag[R] = ClassTag(recordClass)
    val cleanedHandler = jssc.sparkContext.clean(messageHandler.call _)
    createDirectStream[K, V, KD, VD, R](
      jssc.ssc,
      Map(kafkaParams.asScala.toSeq: _*),
      Map(fromOffsets.asScala.mapValues(_.longValue()).toSeq: _*),
      cleanedHandler
    )
  }

  def createDirectStream[K, V, KD <: Decoder[K], VD <: Decoder[V]](
      jssc: JavaStreamingContext,
      keyClass: Class[K],
      valueClass: Class[V],
      keyDecoderClass: Class[KD],
      valueDecoderClass: Class[VD],
      kafkaParams: JMap[String, String],
      topics: JSet[String]
    ): JavaPairInputDStream[K, V] = {
    implicit val keyCmt: ClassTag[K] = ClassTag(keyClass)
    implicit val valueCmt: ClassTag[V] = ClassTag(valueClass)
    implicit val keyDecoderCmt: ClassTag[KD] = ClassTag(keyDecoderClass)
    implicit val valueDecoderCmt: ClassTag[VD] = ClassTag(valueDecoderClass)
    createDirectStream[K, V, KD, VD](
      jssc.ssc,
      Map(kafkaParams.asScala.toSeq: _*),
      Set(topics.asScala.toSeq: _*)
    )
  }
}
```

Note that when I replace the two firsts types [String, String, ...] by [Object, Object, ...] it works great.

Any Idea?

Thank you

Comment: How is `messageHandler` defined?

Comment: `messageHandler` is defined as following:
`val messageHandler: MessageAndMetadata[String, String] => EvtAct = mmd => new EvtAct(mmd.message)`

Comment: Where is `KafkaAvroDecoder` coming from?

Comment: `KafkaAvroDecoder`is a class provided by an artifact and written by Confluent (full class name = [`io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDecoder`](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/v3.0.1/avro-serializer/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafka/serializers/KafkaAvroDecoder.java)). **It is a JAVA class**

Comment: What is the version of your kafka ?

Comment: I use the `spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11` dependency with scala 2.11

Answer (score 0):

From kafka [message](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/0.8.2/core/src/main/scala/kafka/message/MessageAndMetadata.scala) declaration:

```
package kafka.message

import kafka.serializer.Decoder
import kafka.utils.Utils

case class MessageAndMetadata[K, V](topic: String, partition: Int,
                                    private val rawMessage: Message, offset: Long,
                                    keyDecoder: Decoder[K], valueDecoder: Decoder[V]) {

  /**
   * Return the decoded message key and payload
   */
  def key(): K = if(rawMessage.key == null) null.asInstanceOf[K] else keyDecoder.fromBytes(Utils.readBytes(rawMessage.key))

  def message(): V = if(rawMessage.isNull) null.asInstanceOf[V] else valueDecoder.fromBytes(Utils.readBytes(rawMessage.payload))
}
```

and valudecoder as defined fromBytes so my suggestion for you try second argument as `Array[Byte]`

```
val messageHandler: MessageAndMetadata[String, Array[Byte]] => EvtAct = mmd => new EvtAct(mmd.message)

val messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, Array[Byte], KafkaAvroDecoder, KafkaAvroDecoder, EvtAct](
  ssc,
  kafkaParams,
  fromOffsets,
  messageHandler
)
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, but I have the same error, both with `MessageAndMetadata[String, Array[Byte]]` or `MessageAndMetadata[Object, Array[Byte]]`

Comment: if you'r using kafkaAvroEncoder and decoder then the input for encoder will be Object and output Array[Byte].

Comment: Ok then I try to consume Kafka topic, so I juste want to decode an avro encoded topic. How should I create my directStream? If I put these types it compiles: `KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[Object, Object, KafkaAvroDecoder, KafkaAvroDecoder, EvtAct](...)`

Comment: Problem is, in my EvtAct, my constructor takes an Object parameter (`new EvtAct(mmd.message)`), How can I extract fields from this Object? Should I cast it to GenericRecord?

Comment: Try using StringDecoder which will return String from your `Array[Bytes]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128271/discussion-between-thibaut-m-and-faigb).